# I use next.js and i try to do a single post page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i use nextjs and i fetch some dummy data on home and now i want to make a page for each post that i got on home i made it but i feel is not a good code so if someone can healp me clear some things and also learn more on next i will appreciate this a lot. here is the code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import {useEffect} from 'react'

 
const post = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const pid = router.query.pid
    
  async function getdata (){
      if(pid){
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${pid}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getdata()
    }, [pid])

    return(
        <p>wasd{pid}</p>
    )
}


export default post
```

Comment: Try with `Post` instead of `post` ------  `Post=()=>{}` , and then export accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're talking about making components or each different route for each different data.

**FIRST CASE**-If we talk about the first case you can have a folder called components outside your pages for folder and make components there and map that component depending on your data or whatever.

**SECOND CASE**-If you want to have a different route [filename].js is the way to go this represents lets say `localhost:3000/foldername/:filename`. So you can do stuff from here. I'd suggest reading nextjs docs for more info on this routing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is having trouble with the second scenario. As per their code, it indicates its a next page not the react component.

Comment: yeah i need help with the data from the api more